# Merge duplicate values in column

Tags: sql

I have a table `cart_items` with the following data

```
+-----+---------+---------+------------+----------+
| id  | user_id | cart_id | product_id | quantity |
+-----+---------+---------+------------+----------+
| 303 |       9 |      44 |          1 |        2 |
| 305 |       9 |      44 |          3 |        1 |
| 307 |       9 |      44 |          3 |        1 |
| 308 |       9 |      44 |          2 |        1 |
| 309 |       9 |      44 |          6 |        1 |
| 310 |       9 |      44 |          2 |        1 |
+-----+---------+---------+------------+----------+
```

My problem is that there are duplicate products. My desired table would be this

```
+-----+---------+---------+------------+----------+
| id  | user_id | cart_id | product_id | quantity |
+-----+---------+---------+------------+----------+
| 303 |       9 |      44 |          1 |        2 |
| 305 |       9 |      44 |          3 |        2 |
| 308 |       9 |      44 |          2 |        2 |
| 309 |       9 |      44 |          6 |        1 |
+-----+---------+---------+------------+----------+
```

So the difference is that the duplicates `product_id` got merged and increased the `quantity`.

Is there an easy way to do this with an SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `group by user_id, cart_id, product_id` and aggregate:

```
select
  min(id) id, user_id, cart_id, product_id, sum(quantity) quantity
from cart_items
group by user_id, cart_id, product_id
```

Comment: Thank you, group by solved it. Never thought it would be a simple thing like that.